# UTL_FILE to load recursive folders and files with wildcard extension

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

good evening,

I am going to load xls files that are in a local path to oracle, but that are in different folders

and within the folders for years and within the sub folder several files. The load will be total,
delete and reload.

but I have problems with the folder structures and I would like to know if the UTL_FILE package would do my job.

the structure of the folders is similar to:

person(Dir)

------->2020

------->2021

------------>(file) persona_0.xls

------------->(file) persona_new.xls

[image]

how can I do :

1-a loop to go through that folder structure.

2-how I read the different files with a wildcard for the files * person_ *

Thank you so much,

appreciate any help or examples

Greetings.

Comment: In addition to the sound answer by @pmda, I'd ask ... exactly what do you mean by "load" the files?  Insert the entire intact file into a blob column?  Or do you mean to read the file, parse it out, and insert the parsed data as distinct columns into a table? If that is what you mean, you need to be aware that an xls file is in a propriatary (to Microsoft) binary format, that is not easily read by other programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTL_FILE only works with DIRECTORY objects, which are pre-defined pointers to folders on the database server. You cannot use wildcards in the file names or traverse the directory tree. You cannot use UTL_FILE to load files from a client system, either unless (in some cases but not all) they are on a shared network drive that is visible to the database.

From the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS069

> Assuming the user has both READ and WRITE access to the directory
> object USER_DIR, the user can open a file located in the operating
> system directory described by USER_DIR, but not in subdirectories or
> parent directories of this directory.

The only way I have seen this handled in the past is

1. Place all files in the same directory on the DB server
2. Have a shell script that runs on the database server OS list and loop through the files in the directory, and in turn run a SQL script with SQL*Plus to call a stored procedure with each file name as an input. The stored procedure would then open the file in the directory and ingest the data. When the stored procedure and in turn the SQL script were complete, control would return to the shell script which would loop on to the next file in the list and repeat.

OR

3. If all of the files are providing data for the same destination table and have the same record structure, place them all in the same directory and create an external table that points to all of the files at once. You must still name each file explicitly in the external table definition - no wildcards. Then run a stored procedure to perform any ingest operation all at once on the entire data set.

Comment: While what pmdba said is correct using UTL_FILE. I will add that the directory object can be reset in code. This would allow the user to change the directory while using the same directory object. To do this, the following script would need to be executed - 
  

    l_Replace_dir_cmd := 'create or replace directory ' || trim(dir_obj_name) || ' as ' || chr(39) || trim(sub_folder) || chr(39); 
  
    execute immediate l_Replace_dir_cmd; 

This would allow a user to have files in more than one directory.

Comment: From a security perspective, executing DDL in application code is generally considered a bad idea. In many security frameworks it is prohibited. If under some circumstance you *must* use `execute immediate`, use bind variables and not concatenation to construct your command.